Korean letter aren't getting delivered or printed right when they are decrypted and decoded. (COMM between javascript < > java)
Im trying to send some encrypted Data.
Im using AES-128 CBC.
Data is being well encrypted and it gets decrypted perfect on javascript side.
However when the data is delevered to Javacode, encrypted data arrives just fine but as soon as they get decrypted and decoded, only Korean letter are appeared to be broken although English letters and numbers appear just fine.
The codes are below
First one is JS code which sends data. decrypt function is to check if it gets decrypted well.
        function encrypt(text, key, iv) {
            const encodedText = text
            const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv);
            let encrypted = cipher.update(encodedText, 'utf8', 'base64');
            encrypted += cipher.final('base64'); 
            return encrypted;
        }

        function decrypt(encrypted, key, iv) {
            const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv);
            let decrypted = decipher.update(encrypted, 'base64', 'utf8');
            decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');
            return decrypted;
        }

The Second one is JAVA code which gets data and decrypt.
    public String aesDecode(String str) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("INPUT : "+str);
        
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, this.keySpec, new IvParameterSpec(this.iv.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        byte[] decrypted = c.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(str));
        return new String(decrypted, "euc-kr");
    }
}

When I send such data like "ENG한글123"
then it appears to be like "ENG�8羲123"
the only Korean letter part is showing some problem.
Any help or suggestions would be thankful. I'm trying everything but not figuring out yet.
I tried to encode the data first before i send, but the there was a padding problem so i couldn't send any letters longer than 15 cases.
then, I tried to encode first then empty parameter from cipher.final()
but then, byte size wasn't right so it returned error.

It's possible your client machine that reads/receives the data doesn't have the capability to read korean, maybe you can look at polyfilling it?

It seems while encrypting the text, you use UTF8 but when decrypting it, you treat the bytes as euc-kr, shouldn't that be UTF8 too?

Well, thanks for comments. I tried several ways and one of them worked out so I post it just for the record.
I was in a situation that I could not fix Java side at all, so I had to change something on JS.
I encoded the text data into 'euc-kr' first, then encrypted and it worked out.
thanks for comments. I learned other ways to think of when such problem occurs.
the fixed code is below
        function encrypt(text, key, iv) {
        const encodedText = iconv.encode(text, 'euc-kr'); // encode into 'euc-kr first before encrypting'
        const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv);
        let encrypted = cipher.update(encodedText, 'euc-kr', 'base64');
        encrypted += cipher.final('base64'); 
        return encrypted;
    }

    function decrypt(encrypted, key, iv) {
        const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv);
        let decrypted = decipher.update(Buffer.from(encrypted, 'base64'));
        decrypted = Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final()]);
        return iconv.decode(decrypted, 'euc-kr');
    }

